# Общий .env файл для всех микросервисов

Tags: golang, jenkins, микросервисы

Я настраиваю разворачивание микросервисов через Jenkins. Имеется много микросервисов и все они имеют один и тот же .env файл, но на разных инстансах. Идея в том, чтобы держать .env файл для этих микросервисов в едином месте, а при билде и запуске микросервиса на удалённом инстансе каждый раз передавать обновленный .env файл. Можете поделиться своими способами в аналогичной ситуации

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Jenkins в настройках проекта есть раздел `Build Environment`, в нём пункт `Provide Configuration files`, который состоит из списка файлов `Managed Files`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходники файлов задаются в настройках Jenkins, раздел Managed Files

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**План Б**

Если не хочется прописывать конфиги, то необхимый файл можно разместить где-нибудь на внутреннем вебсайте или на общем файловом хранилище, доступном на сборочном сервере, а в этап Build добавить первый шаг Execute, который будет выкачивать файлик из хранилища и класть в нужное место. Так мы тоже делаем, выкачивая пачку ресурсов (лого, css с фирменным стилем) из внутреннего Gitlab перед сборкой.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Честно говоря я склонялся ко второму варианту. Держать единый енв и перед деплоем дёргать его из удалённого инстанса. А что касаемо первого варианта, я не могу найти в своём Jenkins что-то подобное. Это необходимо устанавливать какой-то плагин?

Comment: Да, это плагин, я уже нашел. Название плагина: Config File Provider 
https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Что мешает в gitlab все хранить и тут тебе и версионирование конфигов и контроль за изменением, а плагином SCM выкачивать и класть в нужное место.

Только тут возникает вопрос, как спрятать чувствительные данные, как вариант при сборке использовать ansible vault и через jenkins credentials дешифровать при деплое на хост.